# PySpark read text file into single column dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a text file I'd like to read into a dataframe.  I prefer to read it into a single column.  This was working until I came across a file with `^` in it.

```
raw = spark.read.option("delimiter", "^").csv(data_dir + pair[0])
```

But alas, alack-a-day, the very next broke the pattern.  I don't see an option for `delimiter None`.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using `spark.read.textFile` instead? It may do what you want it to.

Comment: `'DataFrameReader' object has no attribute 'textFile'`

Comment: `spark` in this case would be the Spark Context

Comment: Try [`spark.createDataFrame(sc.textfile("path/to/file"))`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) @BrianDolan